# Array inputs a second integer when a string is inputted

Tags: python

When I insert a string in my array what I expect to happen is it deny the string and give a message explaining how integers are only allowed in the array. Instead the integer that was inserted before gets repeated.

```
import sys

ArrayWidth = 9

mmWidth = 22

ArrayDivider = '=' * 33
ArrayDivider = ArrayDivider.center(ArrayWidth)

mmDivider = '=' * 28
mmDivider = mmDivider.center(mmWidth)

MaxAndMin = 'Maximum & Minimum'
MaxAndMin = MaxAndMin.center(mmWidth)

Array = 'Array'
Array = Array.center(ArrayWidth)

Numbers = []


while True:
    NumberInput = input('Enter a whole number (Exit the loop by pressing "0"): ')
    try:
        NumberInput2 = int(NumberInput)
        if NumberInput2 == 0:
            break
        if NumberInput2 <= 0:
            print('Please enter a number greater then 0.');
            continue;
    except ValueError:
        print("Error. Non-numeric data was entered.")
    except:
        print("Error with input...")
    Numbers.append(NumberInput2)

print('\n'+ArrayDivider+Array+ArrayDivider)
print(sorted(Numbers, key=int),'\n')
print(mmDivider+MaxAndMin+mmDivider)
print('Maximum Number = {}'.format(max(Numbers)))
print('Minimum Number = {}'.format(min(Numbers)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You do `Numbers.append(NumberInput2)` regardless of whether the exception was thrown or not. When `int` raises `ValueError`, `NumberInput2` does not get reassigned and retains the old value.

Try this:

```
while True:
    NumberInput = input('Enter a whole number (Exit the loop by pressing "0"): ')
    try:
        NumberInput2 = int(NumberInput)
        if NumberInput2 == 0:
            break
        if NumberInput2 <= 0:
            print('Please enter a number greater then 0.');
            continue
        Numbers.append(NumberInput2)
    except ValueError:
        print("Error. Non-numeric data was entered.")
    except:
        print("Error with input...")
```

Alternatively, you could `continue` after printing the error message, like you did with nonpositive input.